# Converting Tesla (classical magnetic field unit) to $\rm GeV^2$ (QFT magnetic field unit)

Tags: particle-physics, magnetic-fields, dimensional-analysis, units

I want to do research on hadrons in a presence of an external magnetic field but I need to know how convert Tesla to $\rm GeV^2$.

Can you explain that to me?

Comment: [See this pdf](http://frankwilczek.com/2013/units.pdf) on page 9.

Comment: @John Rennie, What a great reference!

Comment: A gauss is 1G $\approx 2\cdot 10^{-2} \mathrm {eV}^2$, more memorable, so convert to Tesla and GeV ...

Comment: @JohnRennie John  I cannot open the pdf, maybe wrong link?